# How to unlock YouTube for kids under Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I created a Gmail account for my kids to help with distance learning. One thing that puzzles me is that my child cannot access YouTube.com. It will show an error:

"Youtube isn't available with your google account"

It will then direct to YouTube Kids, which is not what I want. It is rather counter productive because YouTube can still be accessed on Microsoft Edge and Firefox.

I searched for hours on the web and I cannot find a solution. The solution all seems to related to Android App but I am using Windows PC. The top search result mentioned I just need to delete my child's profile under my YouTube Kids. But I don't have a YouTube Kids account to begin with. Even if I sign in to my YouTube Kids account, I don't see my child there. Can someone help?

Comment: If your kids are under age of 13, then their google accounts are forced to use YouTube Kids. So, if you find no content violation for your kids in YouTube, then you have to set the age more than 13.

Comment: Try to go [here](https://families.google.com/graduation) to modify you child's account if you have not done it already.

Comment: I tried editing the birthday but neither account will let me do it. The child account says only parent can change. The parent account says "children must be under 13".

Comment: Google have decided that parents shouldn't have the authority to allow YouTube for kids under 13, but at the same time have decided that schools should have the authority to enable YouTube for kids under 13.  They claim that this is to comply with each countries laws, but that isn't true.  No country grants schools more rights to decide on content for children than they do the parents of those same children.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried editing the birthday but neither account will let me do it. The child >account says only parent can change. The parent account says "children must >be under 13". –
> some user

You have to log into the parent account from a parent device, it's impossible to change the age of the child from a kids device.

I changed the age to 1 dag before 13 years, and the next day I went here https://families.google.com/graduation/confirmation  and was able to watch youtube from the kids account, even on mobile devices

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).